# __main__ and scoping in python

Tags: python, scope

I was somehow surprised by the following behavior:

```
def main():
    print "%s" % foo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = "bar"
    main()
```

i.e. a module function has access to enclosing variables in the `__main__`. What's the explanation for it?

Comment: There's no scope `__main__`. There's an `if` that happens to compare a variable that happens to be called `__name__` to something that happens to be the string literal `"__main__"`.

Comment: @delnan: `__main__` is a module, and each module has an associated scope.  Try `import __main__; type(__main__)` in the interpreter (not in IPython).

Comment: @Sven: I know. OP should know at some point. But it seemed to me OP instead confuses if statements with parts of the condition and think `if` introduces a new scope - which would be a more pressing issue. (Admittedly, "There is no scope `__main__` is misleading, strictly speaking)

Comment: @delnan: you're right. In retrospect, I don't know why I was confused. Maybe debugging code at 3 a.m is not such a good idea after all :)

Comment: I just stumbled over this exact same behaviour...thought I was going mad. Glad to see someone else has already asked this question! The behaviour is obvious when the answer is explained...

Comment: I was today years old when I discovered this thing. At least I'm not mad...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Variables in the current modules global scope are visible everywhere in the module -- this rule also holds for the `__main__` module.

From [Guido's tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces):

> At any time during execution, there are at least three nested scopes whose namespaces are directly accessible:
>
> - the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names
> - the scopes of any enclosing functions, which are searched starting with the nearest 
>      enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also non-global names
> - the next-to-last scope contains the current module’s global names
> - the outermost scope (searched last) is the namespace containing built-in names

Comment: @AA: The main script is treated by Python as a module with the name `__main__`.  You even can do `import __main__` (but usually that's a Bad Idea).

Comment: Is it considered good practice to use variables defined in the `__main__` module in functions called in the `__main__` without explicitly passing them?

Comment: @emilaz No, definitely not. Avoid global variables whenever you can. :)

Answer (score 18):

The thing here is that:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = "bar"
```

defines a global variable named foo in that script. so any function of that module will have access to it.

The piece of code listed above is global to the module and not inside any function.

Answer (score 9):

foo is a module global variable (it's not in any function). All scopes within the module can access it.

Answer (score 5):

In python there's the global scope, and functions have their own scopes. So it you define foo under the name==main, it's in the global scope. Also, it's not a mistake to use a variable which hasn't been declared yet, in a function, if it will be declared by the time the function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

As sinelaw pointed out, the way out this annoyance and inadvertent bug/s is to use a function. This function can be within the 'if **main**:' like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def mainlet():
        foo = "bar"
    mainlet()
```