# global variable inside main function python

Tags: python, scope

I wanted to define a global variable in main, i.e., a variable that can be used by any function I call from the main function.

Is that possible?  What'd be a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just pass that variable in as an argument?

Comment: yes, I could, but i was just trying to see if it would be possible to define global vars inside the main function, maybe it's a bad idea...

Comment: global variables only get annoying once you have reallllllyyyy long codes. For smaller codes, however, they are fine.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Fun fact: it used to be used as a countable noun meaning "programme".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_main\_\_ and scoping in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775579/main-and-scoping-in-python)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A variable created *inside* a method (e.g., main) is local by definition. However, you can create a global variable outside the method, and access and change its value from side any other method.

To change its value use the [`global`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) keyword.

Comment: I am trying to define a variable inside the main function that  I can use from other functions that I call from main.  Maybe you are right, and it's not doable since main is just a method.

Comment: @Dnaiel For that you could use parameters to communicate between different parts of the program. I don't know of a way that you can define a global variable from inside a function.

Comment: Actually, you can create a global variable inside a function using `global`. It's just a bad idea, because the variable won't exist until assigned to for the first time. The problem more broadly with your explanation is that you talk of "defining" variables. Python variables are only created on assignment; there isn't a separate definition.

Comment: @Marcin point taken re definition vs creation, replaced the terms

Answer (score 22):

What you want is not possible*. You can just create a variable in the global namespace:

```
myglobal = "UGHWTF"

def main():
    global myglobal # prevents creation of a local variable called myglobal
    myglobal = "yu0 = fail it"
    anotherfunc()

def anotherfunc():
    print myglobal
```

DON'T DO THIS.

The whole point of a function is that it takes parameters. Just add parameters to your functions. If you find that you need to modify a lot of functions, this is an indication that you should collect them up into a class.

`*` To elaborate on why this isn't possible: variables in python are not declared - they are created when an assignment statement is executed. This means that the following code (derived from code posted by astronautlevel) will break:

```
def setcake(taste):
    global cake
    cake = taste
def caketaste():
    print cake #Output is whatever taste was

caketaste()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 7, in <module>
    caketaste()
  File "prog.py", line 5, in caketaste
    print cake #Output is whatever taste was
NameError: global name 'cake' is not defined
```

This happens because when `caketaste` is called, no assignment to `cake` has occurred. It will only occur after `setcake` has been called.

You can see the error here: http://ideone.com/HBRN4y

Comment: The error 'cake' not defined is bcoz you haven't declared it globally at start.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `global` statements. These are relatively simple. To do this, simply define a variable as global before defining the variable itself.
For example:

```
def setcake(taste):
    global cake
    cake = taste
def caketaste():
    print cake 
setcake('tasty')
caketaste() #Output is tasty
```

EDIT:
Sorry, it seems that I misread your question. Allow me to try answering it properly now.

```
def printcake():
    print cake #This function prints the taste of cake when called
def setcake(taste, printq):
    global cake #This makes sure that cake can be called in any function
    cake = taste #sets cake's taste
    if printq: #determines whether to print the taste
        printcake() 
setcake('good', True) #Calls the function to set cake. Tells it to print result. The output is good
```

The output, as seen in code: http://ideone.com/dkAlEp

Comment: What happens if you call `caketaste` before `setcake`?